# What Soul Memory level should I be?

Tags: dark-souls-2

In each area of the game (Let's refer to them by the final bosses) there is a general Soul Memory level that people are when they reach the boss. For example, on the Last Giant route, players are generally Soul Memory level <10,000. But from there, the choices are very open as to where a player will go, (Lost Sinner, Old Dragonslayer, The Rotten).

So what Soul Memory level should I be, in which area, for Coop PvE?

Comment: I think you can have 10k more or less than others and still connect to them. Having 10% of their Soul Memory more or less should also still connect you to them. Besides, Dark Souls 2 can be played in so many different ways, there's almost a guarantee you will find someone near your Soul Memory, wherever you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general there are so many players, that will choose to do more or less the same as you,  that statistical your soul memory in combination with a specific area has little relevance. There will always be someone to Co-op with. Especially in NG.

However, to maximize your chances the best way would be to follow the progression/paths from some of the big internet guides, such as:

http://www.ign.com/wikis/dark-souls-2

http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/areas

If you follow these routes, you will more or less be playing like hundred of thousands of other players, and you should have lots of opportunities to Co-Op.